# Phonegap - background service to call function at specified time?

Tags: cordova, mobile-application, cordova-plugins

A user selects a time for a certain event to happen, like 8 hours in the future... which will update their status on the server at that time. This is fine and works if the app is running, but I need that server update to happen even if the user has closed the app.

For example, Pandora's alarm clock feature. You set the time, close the app, and it still opens and plays at specified time (I use it on Android).

Is this possible with a phonegap app, and how would I implement this to execute the necessary code if the app is closed?

Comment: Also I have faced same problem ,Are you getting any solution ? Please post here thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a [service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). This can be linked to your app, and starts when the phone powers on.